# BackgroundWorker still freezes UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, backgroundworker

I've got the following code,
As you can see the background worker searches for files and in the progress changed event files are added to a listview, however since there is lots of files being added to the listview, the UI becomes unresponsive, I could Sleep the thread in the loops but I don't think that's a good practice, what's the best way to prevent the UI freeze?

to elaborate more, listview is a form control on a form.

```
void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Stack<string> dirs = new Stack<string>(20);
    dirs.Push(e.Argument.ToString());
    while (dirs.Count > 0)
    {
        string currentDir = dirs.Pop();
        string[] subDirs;
        try { subDirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(currentDir); }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { continue; }
        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException) { continue; }

        string[] files = null;
        try { files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(currentDir); }

        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { continue; }
        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException) { continue; }
        foreach (var file in files) { bg.ReportProgress(0, file); }
        foreach (string str in subDirs) { dirs.Push(str); }
    }
}
    void bg_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Can you show a little more context? How are you calling the background worker? is `listView1` a Windows Forms control?

Comment: If you build a complete list, and then add that to your listView in the _WorkComplete event, how does that perform?  Or is the operation too slow for this to be appropriate?

Comment: @IainBallard yes listview is a control.

Comment: @patchandthat I could probably do that, haven't tried it yet, but what's the difference when adding a huge list to the listview? I mean that probably still hogs the UI.

Comment: If you had a lot of files in a directory, updating the UI with the progress (0, file) would make the UI have to do a fair amount of work...

Comment: @PeterRitchie, you are right, what do you think would be the best approach?

Comment: Try taking out line 18 to see if that makes a difference.  If it does, consider a different way of reporting that progress.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, line 18 is the whole point of this code, to retrieve all the file names/paths.

Comment: Not only should you be using the RunWorkerCompleted event handler to add the items to the ListView, you should be calling AddRange once rather than Add multiple times.

Comment: If it's the whole point of the code, you need to make a decision about whether UI responsiveness is important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the issue here is that `ReportProgress` is actually asynchronous.  It doesn't wait for the corresponding UI updates to actually be made before it continue moving on doing work.  Normally this is great.  In most situations there's no compelling reason to slow down your productive work just to go wait for UI updates.

There's one exception though.  If you call `ReportProgress` so often that it doesn't actually have time to complete the previous progress update before the next one is added, what ends up happening is that you fill up the message queue with requests to go update progress.  You have so many files, and getting those lists of files takes very little time.  It actually takes quite a bit less time than it takes to marshal to the UI thread and update the UI.

Because this queue ends up being backed up, any other UI updates need to sit through that long queue before they can do anything.

[Batching up the updates and indicating progress less often is one possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22205239/1159478).  It may or may not be acceptable, given your situation.  It will almost certainly help, but depending on just how long it takes the UI to be updated based on whatever it is that you're doing, and how quickly you can generate data, it's *possible* that even this will cause problems.  If it works for your specific case though, great.

The other option is to change how you update progress such that your worker waits for the UI update before continuing.  Obviously this is something that you should avoid unless you *need* to do it, because it means that while you aren't freezing the UI while you do your work, your work will take a fair bit longer.  While there are any number of ways of doing this, the simplest of which is likely to just use `Invoke` (*not* `BeginInvoke`):

```
foreach (var file in files)
    listView1.Invoke(new Action(()=>listView1.Items.Add(file));
```

While calling `Invoke` from a `BackgroundWorker` is generally code smell, and should be avoided, this is a somewhat exceptional case.

Note that even if you *do* end up resorting to using `Invoke` here I would still suggest batching the invokes such that you add more than just one item per invoke.  If the number of files in a single directory is sufficiently low, put the whole `foreach` inside the `Invoke`, and if your subdirectories tend to have very few files (i.e, they're very deep, not broad) consider even putting all of the files into a temp list until it's large enough to be worth batching into an `Invoke`.  Play around with different approaches based on your data, to see what works best.

Comment: Great point about the UI message queue getting backed up due to the other thread trying to update it asynchronously. I got here because I was having the same problem and hadn't thought of the message queue issue. My solution was to use a private DateTime variable to track the last time the UI was updated, and then, in my ProgressChanged event, only update the UI when (DateTime.Now - MyVariable).TotalMilliseconds was greater than 10 -or- if the current iteration happened to be the last one. Then I just set the variable to DateTime.Now for the next time the event gets fired. Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`bg.ReportProgress()` is meant to report the overall progress of the BackgroundWorker back to the UI thread, so you can inform your users as to the progress. However, you're using it to actually add strings to a ListView. You're better off compiling the list of files into an in-memory list and then populating listView1 once when the background worker completes:

```
public void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   foreach (var file in MyFileListVar){
       listView1.Items.Add(file);
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that it can end up taking so long to update the listview with all of these items that the UI will be frozen for quite some time.  The fact that it's happening with the OP's code would lead me to believe it would *likely* happen with this code as well.

Comment: @Servy is right, tried that, does not make a difference, no UI response at all, just like the code I'm using.

Comment: If there are so many items that must be added to the list that your UI is grinding to a halt, then you probably need to find a better way of retrieving lists of files in batches with some sort of pagination mechanism. I'm curious how much memory your application is eating up trying to render such a large list of items at once.

Answer (score 2):

Try to load multiple files (lets say between 10~50), then send them back to the UI thread (ie: `bg.ReportProgress`) instead of sending every file separately.